# With python, how to split string in each row of a csv file

Tags: python, csv

[This is how the csv file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yaXF.png)

I have this banking dataset with all the variable names and item staying in the same cells of the column A. How do I separate them properly by ";", and place them in each column of the csv file following column A, with Python？

For example, all the variable names are stored in A1 :

age;"job";"marital";"education";"default";"housing";"loan";"contact";"month";"day_of_week";"duration";"campaign";"pdays";"previous";"poutcome";"emp.var.rate";"cons.price.idx";"cons.conf.idx";"euribor3m";"nr.employed";"y"

and one of the data in B1:
56;"housemaid";"married";"basic.4y";"no";"no";"no";"telephone";"may";"mon";261;1;999;0;"nonexistent";1.1;93.994;-36.4;4.857;5191;"no"

same with the data in A2, A3, A4......

instead I would like to figure out a way to separate all of them by ";" and place them in separated cells B1, C1, D1..... so they look like:

____A______B_____C______
1|**Age_**|____job____|**marital_|.....

2|__56_**|**housemaid_|_married**|.....
......
......(I hope to do the same for all the rows)

I want to modify the file with Python, so with read.csv from pandas I can read/analyze the data with gridlines. I think I did something similar before with R.

Comment: I am not sure @narko answer everything you ask, can you show us some example of what you want?

Comment: You need to describe more clearly what is the raw data looks like

Comment: Instead of showing a screenshot of Excel, please provide a few lines of raw data (e.g. open in notepad).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader

Comment: @Whitefret I tried my best to show you what I want

Comment: @KramerLi I tried my best to describe how it looks like, plus the picture.

Comment: @Zenith To me, you already have your data formatted as a .csv, you just need to tell excel that your separator is ;

Comment: If you have to do this once I think telling excel that the separator is ";" is ok, but if you have to do this a lot then an automated script would be the best choice IMO.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should try to do it yourself first and then ask a question with a code sample.

Second, please accept answers that solve your question. (As I see the previous one wasn't accepted)

Thirdly, here is my shot at the code.

For example if you have your data set (I simplified mine, but its along the lines of your data):

```
"cat";"dog";"moose"
"moose";"cat";"dog"
```

And here is the code:

```
import csv

csv_rows = []

with open('animals.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    orig_csv = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in orig_csv:
        csv_rows.append(row)

with open("animals_1.csv", "wb") as csvfile:
    w = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=",")
    for row in csv_rows:
        w.writerow(row)
```

Make sure you are using the correct delimiter for reading/writing the CSV! As the data set that you have would look fine on my PC.

Edited: changed the sample code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

based on my understanding, the raw format of your data is like:

```
[root@ES01 ~]# cat /tmp/test.txt 
c1;c2;c3;c4;c5
v1;v2;v3;v4;v5
```

You want to change to

```
c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
v1,v2,v3,v4,v5
```

I think you can

```
f=open('/tmp/test.txt')
for line in f.readlines():
    print line.replace(';',',')
```

Comment: it would be a bad solution if there is ";" in the data.

Comment: @Whitefret yes. any suggestion to avoid this? does the csv model can avoid this ?